# Is possible to use hyperledger for storing public data.....?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I need to store some public(non secure) data in hyperledger. And need to display it to public. I need to know something that.

1. Is possible or suitable to use hyperledger for storing public data...??
2. Is possible to connect peers or nodes to my hyperledger composer network from Clint side (like bitcoin core wallet or ethereum core)...??
3. Which is a better choice for General DB(like mysql) or hyperledger for keeping the trust of public data(please read and understand my situation )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the answer is it depends.

there are a number of factors to consider:

1. type of data
2. size of data
3. since it's public is it likely that the volume of requests is high?

when you use composer, you have assets and these assets represent the data you want to maintain on the ledger. if that data is relatively simple in structure, then you should not have an issue. By default the composer api will give you direct endpoints for each one of your asset types. If you have some rules that decide how you create assets and what values to save in certain places then you might have to ignore those and create some transactions instead. Transactions can also create assets, the advantage being that you can apply complex rules at that point.

You can create a Public org with one peer.
Your bna should be fairly simple. Create it, deploy it to your peer and instantiate it.

create a network card with one public identity, then finally an api.

This would give you all you need to interact with your network. 
To achieve this you can follow one of the simple tutorials on hyperledger's website to get it all up and running.

Then I guess it's POC time, have a look and see what you think. There are limitations, for example, at the moment you can not limit the amount of data you retrieve via the api.
There is also the fact that composer is not in active development anymore and who knows how much longer it will be supported.

At some point you will probably have to switch to the more complex way of working with hyperledger, using one of the SDKs available to build your chaincode.

For your third question, to be completely honest, I would go with a classic approach, a standard database, like sql , mysql, mongo, whatever is appropriate and a standard api. In my opinion Hyperledger is far from ready for a serious production system and far too complicated to work with.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Please give something idea about my 3rd question.

Comment: added something for your third question, at the end

Comment: My third question is Which is a better choice for General DB(like mysql) or hyperledger for keeping the trust of public data..???

Comment: Hey.. Please give a response. Which is a better choice for General DB(like mysql) or hyperledger for keeping the trust of public data..?

Comment: hyperledger is not a database replacement. if you have a lot of data, chances are you could use hyperledger and a normal database at the same time as well. it depends on what kind of data, how much data and how often it changes

Comment: Thanks again. May I ask an another question please. Is possible to connect peers or nodes to my hyperledger composer network from Clint side (I don't know more in hyperledger)..???

Comment: when you use composer, after you create and deploy you network, you can generate a REST api which allows you to talk to it. From your client side application, all you need to do is talk to that API. as for creating peers, you can script all that and expose it somehow to a client app if you really need that. I would dtart on hyperledger website for that though, get some scripts running, then you can think how to maybe automate the process.